# cefsharp.browsersubprocess.exe not running on some 64 bit systems

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I am using CefSharp-WPF in my application and its running fine on almost all 64 bit machines but for some. My main window opens, but page is not rendered on it i.e empty

Cefsharp.browsersubprocess.exe doesn't run on all problematic machines. If i try to run it manually i.e. for testing purpose, it automatically gets killed as soon as it starts.

I am using CefSharp-WPF v53.0.0 on 64 bit machines, cef.redist.x64 version is 3.2785.1482.

Regards

Comment: It might be crashing for some reason. Take a look here: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#unmanaged-crashes-when-the-process-dies ... it might help find what's going on. One other thing to try, if you are using "AnyCPU" as your "platform target" in your .NET app....try using "x86" (i.e. 32bit) instead.

Comment: Upgrade to a newer version, know issue, read the release notes.

Comment: that worked. version 55.0.0